# Is it possible to trigger onChange event with setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, state, onchange

Does react onChange event only triggers when user types into a input field?

I want to set a dirty flag on a form so when user navigates out of a page it will trigger a dialog asking if he really want to discard changes. The isDirty flag is in my component's state and it is set when user types into input fields. I was afraid that when i initialize state in constructor with predefined input values it might accidentialy trigger onChange resulting in state change and leading to setting isDirty to true when user didn't even type into a field.

Right now it works. Is this expected behavior and am I 100% safe?

Code example: are there any chances handleChange will be triggered by initializing state in constructor or setting state in button onClick handler?

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { exampleInput: "exampleValue" };
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({
         exampleInput: event.target.value,
      });
    }

    onExampleButtonClick = () => {
      this.setState({
         exampleInput: "buttonClicked",
      })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <input name="exampleInput" value={this.state.exampleInput} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <button onClick={this.onExampleButtonClick}>Example Button</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code example

Comment: added code example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can use componentDidUpdate and check state inside there if the condition is valid you could do something like this

```
var ev2 = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
input.dispatchEvent(ev2);
```

where input would be a ref to the element you want to trigger the event upon more on refts here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: so we need some additional magic to make it happen right? onChange won't trigger with controlled components by using... well only setState, otherwise it would lead to infinite loop? I just want to make sure it is expected behavior that this event doesn't trigger with just calling setState or initializing state in constructor when component is being created

Comment: Anyhow the onChange event should not trigger if you programatically change its binded state from another place, I might have misunderstood your question

Comment: you are right, but I'm already setting dirty flag in onChange event and I get the result (my flag is only set to true when I type from keyboard). I was just wondering if it is safe (if anything other than typing is able to trigger input's handleChange i.e. initializing state or setting state via setState)

Comment: Yes it should be safe :).. please mark the answer if this helped you